# Need a fix for M3U8 files to work properly with videojs on all the browsers

Tags: html, reactjs, video.js, m3u8

I am using VideoJS player version 7.20.2 in my React application, which works fine with all the formats. It is mainly working with m3u8 as well. However, a few m3u8 files are not working, and the error "Playback cannot continue. No available working or supported playlists."

Her is the sample code

```
const videoJsOptions = {
  autoplay: true,
  fluid: true,
  playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
  controls: true,
  responsive: true,
  aspectRatio: '16:9',
  techOrder: ['html5', 'youtube', 'vimeo'],
  youtube: { autohide: 1 , autoplay: false },
  poster: carouselID?.poster,
  html5: {
    nativeTextTracks: false,
         },

  sources: [{
    src: "https://mps.lib.harvard.edu/vod/_definst_/smil:s3/drs-delivery-prod/491690138.smil/playlist.m3u8",
    type: "application/x-mpegurl"
  }]
};
```

Comment: It also does not work with audio tag, this m3u8 is working on safari with video tag

Comment: @hobbs There are many other audio m3u8 those corrects with video tag with videojs

Comment: Probably it's because it doesn't contain any `EXT-STREAM-INF` directives declaring the codecs and formats, so MSE can't make a playability decision on it. This isn't the kind of stream that's meant to be played that way.

Comment: The same m3u8 is working when I use videojs using jquery and javascript without react